# How to save a file with .pdf format in a flex4 mobile application:

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want to save a file in .pdf format in a flex4 mobile application, But the problem is that
 its saving the file in .pdf format when am running the app using emulator from my flash builder 4.5
 but it doesn't saving the file in a mobile device, means when am running the app's build in a android 
 device its not saving the file .

To save the file am using filereference class’s save() method . Is their any other way to save any file in a mobile device in PDF format ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Mobile AIR; you should be able to use the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class to save a file.  I think you'll need to use a [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) to write the PDF binary into the instance of the File class.